Как открывать файлы с разными именами последовательно?
Есть папка, в которой большое количество файлов .txt с разными именами, первая часть имени содержит дату, вторая часть, можно считать, случайна.
Как открывать для чтения файл, не зная его точного имени один за другим по порядку до конца папки? Может можно из Windows подчерпнуть информацию какой по счету это файл и как-то получить его имя и передать в программу?

Findfirstfile, findnextfile. В Фортране могут быть обертки для этих функций

Почитал, оберток нигде нет, все пишут что надо пользоваться WinAPI. Не подскажите, как вызвать эти функции?

В msdn есть пример на С https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory

Видимо, придётся ещё С++ изучать)

Есть ещё вариант обработать результаты вызова команды system (dir, ls)

А можно немного поподробнее? Просто я не понимаю о чем вы говорите, где про это можно почитать?

В командной строке windows вы можете сделать "dir *.txt /B" и увидеть список файлов с данной маской в текущей папке. Перенаправив вывод в файл или себе в поток ввода, можно обработать эти файлы. Вот какой-то пример (для линукса, с ls). Пример написать не могу, Фортран уже много лет назад забыл.

Однако, если вы умеете использовать функции из системных библиотек Windows, то findnextfile мне кажется предпочтительнее. Коме того, в современных фортранах могут быть готовые библиотеки для таких вещей - тогда вам останется только вызвать что-то типа FILES.GetAllFiles (название абстрактное, я не в курсе)

Я использую компилятор Intel Fortran, там очень много всего. Наверное действительно стоит поискать и узнать название процедуры, которая сможет это сделать

Резюме по вопросу. Во-первых, ссылки на англоязычные ответы: Listing the contents of a directory in Fortran и Printing Directory Listing in Fortran.
Во-вторых, относительно содержания тех ответов:

Использование общеупотребительного расширения Fortran call system(...) выглядит сравнительно просто и, при правильном использовании, более менее надёжно. Правда, команда записи списка файлов в файл зависит от системы;
Обвязка над функциями API POSIX opendir()/readdir() несколько сложнее, кроме того для WinAPI потребует доработки, зато эффективно. Правда, использование readdir() небезопасно в многопоточных программах, а использование readdir_r() тоже потребует доработки;
Использование готовых библиотек ссылается на ссылки из документации GNU Fortran. За IFPORT сейчас трудно что-то сказать ввиду заскоков Intel и госдепа США. Модули NAG, как бы, входят в проприетарную библиотеку NAG и, вероятно, Вам недоступны. flibs, в этой части, грязновато написан, могут быть проблемы с многопоточностью и не только, т.к. он делает chdir() и прочая, прочая. fortranposix выглядит заброшенным.


Помогло, спасибо!
